If 2 functions, say $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, are both $\in$ $\Theta(h(x))$, then does that mean $f \in \Theta(g)$?
I'm not sure how to exactly prove this formally with the definitions of Big-$\Theta$. Also, would this apply to Big-O or Big-$\Omega$, or no?
We have that (by combining the definitions of Big-O and Big-$\Omega$ for Big-$\Theta$):
$C_1 |h(x)| \leq |f(x)| \leq C_2 |h(x)|$ for $x > k_1$
and
$C_3 |h(x)| \leq |g(x)| \leq C_4 |h(x)|$ for $x > k_2$
I know by definition of Big-$\Omega$ it tells us that $C_1$ and $C_3$ are positive (from Rosen's Discrete Math book):

And by the following lemma (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4938153/801877):

Lemma. Let $f(x)$ be $O(g(x))$ and let $C_0$ and $k_0$ be any constants.
Then there exist constants $C$ and $k$ such that $C > C_0$, $k > k_0$, and such that $|f(x)| \leq C|g(x)|$ whenever $x > k$.
Informally speaking, this lemma says that when applying the definition
of big-O, you can assume the constants $C$ and $k$ are as great as you
need them to be.

We can assume $C_2$ and $C_4$ to be $ > 0$ and $k_1$ and $k_2$ to be both $> 1$.
This is because $C_1 |h(x)| \leq |f(x)|$ for $x > l$ and $|f(x)| \leq C_2 |h(x)|$ for $x > m$. By the lemma, $m$ can be $> 1$ and since $k_1 = max(l, m)$, then $k_1$ must be $> 1$. Same argument applies for $k_2$
But I'm not sure how I can manipulate these inequalities in such a way that would prove $f \in \Theta(g)$, especially when trying to deal with possibilities of either $f$, $g$, or $h$ $= 0$.
Kindly please let me know.

What have you tried?

@Malady My bad I'll add that in the edit

@Malady just added!

For one bound of $\Theta(g)$, for $x> \max {k_1,k_2}$, $$\lvert f(x)\rvert \le C_2 \lvert h(x)\rvert \le \frac{C_2}{C_3} \lvert g(x)\rvert$$. Similarly for the other bound. This requires the $C$-constants to be positive.

I would start by showing that the relation $f \in \Theta(g)$ is symmetric and transitive.

It definitely wouldn't apply to big-$O$ or $\Omega$.

@arkeet I think I see what you're saying. Kindly could you type out an answer just so I make sure we're on the same page?
